How to fix suspend/resume/screen blanking/non-resuming issues on MSI GE76 Raider 11UE (Nvidia Proprietary driver hell)?
...and still have 3D acceleration enough for running Blender and occassionally gaming (using Vulkan-based Steam games).
System specs that matter:

Nvidia RTX 3060
64GB RAM
11th gen intel i7
Latest Nvidia driver (not the open kernel version - does this make a difference, btw?, I haven't checked, since the open kernel driver is so recent and untested.).

Basically:

I'm unable to consistently suspend/resume if I run Gnome/KDE -
whether Wayland or X11.
With X11, the system freezes after some time
(so long as I'm using multiple monitors). This is a known bug which
has not had traction in some time (If I can track the bug down on
Launchpad I'll link it here).
On Wayland or X11, Gnome will allow suspending, but will crash on resume.
On Wayland, KDE/Plasma was working before. Since upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, it works when it wants to. It's unpredictable, and I can't seem to track down the cause.
On other desktops, such as UKUI (which I tested), it seems to work just fine for suspending or resuming. Or at least, sometimes. The behaviour is so inconsistent I've given up trying to find one desktop environment that just works.

Note: This issue appears to be related to the Nvidia proprietary driver. So my question is:
What can I do to make it "behave" as it should. Is there maybe an ACPI rule that I need to tweak? Is this a case where I should just do a fresh install? (That won't be easy!)
Or should I switch to the bleeding edge Open Source drivers (either NVK or Nouveau)? Would either of these allow me to use my card sufficiently well enough to run Blender (with Cycles, using the card) or games such as NMS (via Steam)?
